# How do we let the API consumer know what data required to create a resource in RESTful?

Tags: rest

Let’s say there’s a new student to be created. So the design will be POST on /student. But how do the api consumer know what all fields required to create a student? No RESTful document I could find specifying this.

Comment: Generate documentation pages for you api and specify it there. Alternativly, use graphql. It's an entirely different api model, but it has enforceable schemas and it's really nice to work with.

Comment: But as per RESTful principle that APIs should be self-descriptive.

Comment: huh? Point me to the source of this claim. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I think the OP missed the point of what _self-descriptive_ means. I've quoted Fielding's dissertation in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47457277/1426227).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just depends on your requirements. You should have API documentation where you can tell the API consumers what data should be at http POST request.
You tell the rules))

Comment: But as per RESTful principle that APIs should be self-descriptive.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It still is self descriptive, but only for HTTP methods that should be used to manipulate with data.

Answer (score 2):

> How do we let the API consumer know what data required to create a resource in RESTful?

Short answer: documentation.

Document your web API, list the available endpoints, the supported methods, the media types that your endpoints will consume and produce, the required input, the expected output, the error codes, etc.

---

> But as per RESTful principle that APIs should be self-descriptive.

You've missed the whole point of what *self-descriptive* means. See the following quote from the [chapter 5](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of Roy T. Fielding dissertation, that defines the REST architecture:

> REST enables intermediate processing by constraining messages to be self-descriptive: interaction is stateless between requests, standard methods and media types are used to indicate semantics and exchange information, and responses explicitly indicate cacheability.

The [chapter 6](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm) explores the approach of applying [REST to HTTP](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_3) and also gives more details about [self-descriptive messages](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_3_2).

Comment: Indeed, this appears to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide full information and documentation about how to use your `REST API` - use [swagger](https://swagger.io/). It is mostly used tools for that. Especially look at [swagger editor](https://swagger.io/swagger-editor/).